# css expanding width with rectangle

Tags: jquery, html, css

The background where the text stands, has an border radius to fit the circle.
When I hover the circle to expand the `width`, it still haves an `border-radius`and is not an rectangle. I tried to fix it with `#becomemembercontainer:hover {border-radius:none;}`

Here's an link to my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zr2a8h8y/4/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/zr2a8h8y/5/

```
// #becomemembercontainer:hover {
  (...)
}
```

This is an invalid syntax for comments in CSS. You should use: `/* comment */` instead. ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments )

Comment: Serious? That I didn't saw that little stupid mistake, well sorry!